# How to exclude firebase-admin generation in angular 16 with SSR when building browser side app?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, firebase-admin

I use firebase-admin only on the server side and I don't have references to it on the browser side, and yet when building the application, the firebase-admin module is loaded in the file dist/browser/main.js.

I would like firebase-admin to load only on the server side and skipped on the browser side. Now i have warning in browser, but i don't use firebase in browser side

*firebase-admin appears to have been installed in an unsupported environment.
This package should only be used in server-side or backend Node.js environments,
and should not be used in web browsers or other client-side environments.*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.